# React/Redux with Firebase getting compile error, Module not found: Can't resolve 'debounce'

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux

I am creating a React/redux app in VS Code and connecting with firebase. I have installed a package, it installed successfully but I am getting error when compiling, I tired to re install the packages and did not get any error but still getting compile error, can anybody help?

packages installed

> npm install react-redux-firebase redux-firestore

Error I am getting

> ./node_modules/redux-firebase/lib/createFirebaseMiddleware.js
>   Module not found: Can't resolve 'debounce' in '[my file system location]\[my project name]\node_modules\redux-firebase\lib'

**Update** : I was installing the wrong package, I was installing "redux-firebase" but actual package was "redux-firestore". Now it is working.

Comment: I'd consider checking out [this post](https://github.com/colbyr/redux-firebase/issues/2). redux-firebase hasn't been updated in over 3 years. I'd consider moving towards other alternatives.

Comment: I am using the latest namespace mentioned in that post.

Comment: Please read the **entire** post.